# how to know when play is finished in tts when using the TalkBack google service

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a project for the blind that requires a combination of two text-to-speech engines on Android.
The problem is synchronizing the output of these two engines together, when the original text-to-speech engine object is created by Google TalkBack.

I have a main text to speech engine in Android which is supposed to be Dual Language. For synthesizing the second language, this engine creates an instance of the second engine that needs to be electable. It processes the input text and determines their language and then calls the appropriate engine for each language.

Please note that the second engine, which is related to the English language, must be selectable from among the engines available in the system.

There is a class called UtteranceProgressListener that has an [onDone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener#onDone(java.lang.String)) function that is called when the text is finished playing.

But because the instance of the main engine is created by Google TalkBack, it is not possible to call the [setOnUtteranceCompletedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener)) function for it in the main program. Here is the main problem.

I can get onDone from second instance engine. that the sound of the second language is played exactly after the first language. But I can't get onDone for the main instance engine by Google TalkBack and I don't know how to solve this problem.

But different ways and questions:

1.

First, does [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) allow access to the service to access the [TextToSpeech](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech)  object created by Google TalkBack or the Event that specifies play audio is finished?

2.

Second: building a nested text to speech engine. In such a way that the main engine only divides the text into dual languages and then create two instances from the other two engines. The problem here is that as far as I understand, each package can only implement and name one [TextToSpeechService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService)  engine. Therefore, it is necessary to re-implement TextToSpeech class to create an instance of the nested engine. Is there a feasible method?

3.

Third: The UtteranceProgressListener class has an [onAudioAvailable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener#onAudioAvailable(java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D)) function that provides us with the synthesized buffer. We can receive the buffer, resample and write the main text to speech engine buffer. The problem with this method is that the Sync Thread has to write to the buffer. However, onAudioAvailable is called by the Sync Thread of the second engine and therefore play is not performed. Perhaps it is necessary to design a pipe from which the Main Sync Thread reads and writes to the buffer. Is this feasible?

[ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech#ACTION_TTS_QUEUE_PROCESSING_COMPLETED)  broadcast cannot be used, because it specifies the end of the synthesis, not the end of the play!

```
public class TtsService extends TextToSpeechService {
    private static final String TAG = TtsService.class.getSimpleName();

    private SpeechSynthesis mEngine;
    private SynthesisCallback mCallback;
    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;


    private static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_1 = "fas";


    private static final String DEFAULT_COUNTRY_1 = "IRN";
    private static final String DEFAULT_VARIANT_1 = "";
    /////////////////English
    // en eng
    private static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_2 = "eng";

    private static final String DEFAULT_COUNTRY_2 = "USA";
    private static final String DEFAULT_VARIANT_2 = "";

    private String mLanguage = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_1;
    private String mCountry = DEFAULT_COUNTRY_1;
    private String mVariant = DEFAULT_VARIANT_1;

......
```